# Angular1 location html5mode equivalent in angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to find where I can enable html5mode in angular2. Unfortunately couldnt find it out from the documentation or anywhere. I am using gulp and browser-sync to load my files. 
I have seen that many says to use connect-modrewrite something like

```
browserSync.instance = browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: ['app'],
      middleware: [
        proxyMiddleware,
        modRewrite([
          '^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]'
        ])
      ]
    },
  });
```

I set it but still it doesnt work and I get 404 for anything but the main url.
Any clues on this?

Comment: HTML5 pushState is the default in Angular2. You can also switch to `HashLocationStrategy`.

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is the [`PathLocationStrategy`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/PathLocationStrategy-class.html) which is the default `LocationStrategy`

**NOTE**

When using this you will need to set your server to redirect *ALL* requests to the root URL. For example if your user requests `myApp.com/someRoute` then assets will be resolved from that url which is incorrect. Instead you want the server to serve the `index.html` page regardless of the route specified, but still keep the route intact so that it can be used by the client-side application.

Also be sure to set your `<base path="/" />` tag in the head of your HTML.

Comment: I guess It works by itself. I solved it but now it tries to load any script or link tag that I have in index.html from the new URL. so If my path is http://localhost:3000/myapp/test it tries to load all the script assets from http://localhost:3000/myapp/test/main.css rather than from http://localhost:3000

Comment: @user3205675 I've updated the above with the reason your application is behaving that way.

Comment: This link is broken

Comment: Link should now be updated to the latest documentation.